# jQuery - How to stop drop down menu items flashing on and off (and rolling down and up) multiple times

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, hover, menubar

I have a drop down menu bar at the top of my webpage with six tabs (some of them drop downs, some just normal single tabs). I animate the drop down feature and a fade-in colour-change for the tabs using jQuery.

If I hover over a tab, then the one beside it and go back and forth quickly between the two, when I stop the mouse, both tabs will flash on and off multiple times (meaning fading from the hover background colour to the non-hover colour), depending on how many times I alternated between the two. If one of the tabs is a dropdown tab, the drop down contents will slide down and up over and over before finally stopping.

I realize users of the webpage will probably not treat my menu this way, but I have noticed this behaviour sometimes when testing my page normally. The above procedure is just a more obvious way of testing the flaw.

I'm not sure how to tell the function to only fire if the tab is at rest (not displaying the hover colour or dropdown contents), anyone have any ideas?

Here is my javascript code for the dropdown:

```
$(" .dropdown li").hover(function(){

    if ($(this).parent().attr('class') == "subdrop")
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#AAC4D1", color: "white"}, "fast");
    else
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#2A5B84", color: "white"}, "fast");

    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible", display: "none"}).slideDown(400);

},function(){
    if ($(this).parent().attr('class') == "subdrop")
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "white", color: "#2A5B84"}, "fast");
    else
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#F3F3F3", color: "#2A5B84"}, "fast");

        $(this).find('ul:first').slideUp(400);
});
```

I found a forum post online where someone changed the `.hover()` to `.bind('mouseenter', function(){` and switched the callback function to `.bind('mouseleave', function(){`, but I tried implementing this and it did nothing to solve the problem.

Comment: Quick question.. are you planning on using this website for mobile use as well? I only ask this because I am pretty sure that hover is a useless feature for mobile users and you may as well switch to an .onclick or something similar to that.

Comment: We aren't focusing on mobile development. It would be nice for users to be able to navigate to the page on mobile devices but that would just be a bonus, and the dropdown functionality isn't absolutely necessary to browse through the site.